# Error:”invalid_grant”, Description:””, Uri:”” while using service account from my local machine

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth, service-accounts

I got below error while using service account from my local machine

Error:

> invalid_grant”, Description:””, Uri:””.

see code below -

```
 string[] scopes = new string[] {
    AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics
 }; // view and manage your Google Analytics data

 var keyFilePath = @
 "c:\xxxxxxx.p12"; // Downloaded from https://console.developers.google.com
 var serviceAccountEmail = "xxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com"; // found https://console.developers.google.com

 //loading the Key file
 var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
 var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail) {
    Scopes = scopes
 }.FromCertificate(certificate));

 var service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Analytics API Sample",
 });
 string profileId = "xxxxxx";
 DataResource.RealtimeResource.GetRequest request = service.Data.Realtime.Get(String.Format("ga:{0}", profileId), "rt:activeUsers");
 RealtimeData feed = request.Execute();
```

Comment: without code its hard to predict the reason

Comment: check the time on your PC is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

**invalid_grant** has two common causes.

- Your server’s clock is not in sync with [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol). (Solution: check the server time if its incorrect fix it. )
- The refresh token limit has been exceeded.       (Solution: Nothing you can do they cant have more refresh tokens in use)
  Applications can request multiple refresh tokens. For example, this is useful in situations where a user wants to install an application on multiple machines.  In this case, two refresh tokens are required, one for each installation. When the number of refresh tokens exceeds the limit, older tokens become invalid. If the application attempts to use an invalidated refresh token, an invalid_grant error response is returned. The limit for each unique pair of OAuth 2.0 client and is 25 refresh tokens (note that this limit is subject to change). If the application continues to request refresh tokens for the same Client/Account pair, once the 26th token is issued, the 1st refresh token that was previously issued will become invalid. The 27th requested refresh token would invalidate the 2nd previously issued token and so on.

I have also read of a third which is if you don't include `access_type=offline` in your request.  I have never had an issue with this one myself

Comment: How can i sync pc time with ntp server?

Comment: most servers have a NTP daemon running to keep the server in sync.   I would check that to start with.

Comment: I have sync server time with ntp server time,but still i am facing this issue.

Comment: and you have access to the Google analytics real-time API correct? And the service account has been granted access to the Google Analytics account you are trying to access?

Comment: I see that you are using the Real-time api.  However the Real-time API is still in beta do you have beta access to it?  Have you tried  running it against the reporting api and seeing if you get the same error message.

Comment: I tried below code instead of real time api but still fcing same issue.      ManagementResource.AccountSummariesResource.ListRequest list = service.Management.AccountSummaries.List(); list.MaxResults = 1000;  

            AccountSummaries feed = list.Execute();

Comment: Then I don't know what your problem could be its normally NTP issues.